# Spark Kafka Producer throwing Too many open files Exception

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to run a Spark Kafka Job written in Java to produce around 10K records per batch to a Kafka Topic. This is a spark batch job which reads 100(total 1million records) hdfs part files sequentially in a loop and produce each part file of 10K records in a batch. 
I am using org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer API

Getting below exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
....
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
....
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
```

Below is the configurations:

```
Cluster Resource availability:
---------------------------------
The cluster has more than 500 nodes, 150 Terabyte total memory, more than 30K cores

Spark Application configuration:
------------------------------------
Driver_memory: 24GB
--executor-cores: 5
--num-executors: 24
--executor-memory: 24GB

Topic Configuration:
--------------------
Partitions: 16
Replication: 3

Data size
----------
Each part file has 10K records
Total records 1million
Each batch produce 10K records
```

Please suggest some solutions for this as this is a very critical issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the code of the spark job?

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka, every topic is (optionally) split into many partitions. For each partition some files are maintained by brokers (for index and actual data).

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic topic_name
```

will give you the number of partitions for topic `topic_name`. The default number of partitions per topic `num.partitions` is defined under `/etc/kafka/server.properties`

The total number of open files could be huge if the broker hosts many partitions and a particular partition has many log segment files.

You can see the current file descriptor limit by running

```
ulimit -n
```

You can also check the number of open files using `lsof`:

```
lsof | wc -l
```

To solve the issue you either need to change the limit of open file descriptors:

```
ulimit -n <noOfFiles>
```

or somehow reduce the number of open files (for example, reduce number of partitions per topic).